# Node JS cannot post error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I am unsure as to why I am getting an error for POST-ing a form. I am using mongoose to connect to mongodb and using Jade as my view engine. I am trying to POST an update and not a new account into the db, and using a cookie to pull the user's info. So it is the Edit User Profile page. Everything works on the Jade file and looks right, just when I hit the submit button it goes to a:

```
Cannot POST /editUserProfile
```

My mongoose User file:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs'),
    SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;


var UserSchema = new Schema({ 
    email: { type: String, required: true, lowercase:true, index: { unique: true } },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
    firstName: {type: String, required: true},
    lastName: {type: String, required: true},
    phone: {type: Number, required: true},
    birthday: {type: Date, required: true}
});


UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;
    console.log("email exists");
    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
    // generate a salt
    bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function(err, salt) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        // hash the password along with our new salt
        bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, null, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            // override the cleartext password with the hashed one
            user.password = hash;
            next();
        });
    });    
});

UserSchema.methods.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, cb) {
    bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function(err, isMatch) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        cb(null, isMatch);
    });
};


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

My route file:

```
exports.editUserProfile = function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.signedCookies.userid, function(err,user) {
        if(err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
    res.render('editUserProfile', {title: 'Weblio', 
        ufirstName: user.firstName,
        ulastName: user.lastName,
        uemail: user.email,
        uphone: user.phone,
        ubirthday: user.birthday
    });
    //, user: user.firstName, - taken out after title
        }
    });
};

exports.editUserProfilePost = function(req, res) {
        var updateUser = new User ({
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            birthday: new Date(req.body.birthday) 
        });
        updateUser.save(function(err){
            console.log("here 3");
            if(!err) {
                console.log("here3a");
                res.render('userProfile', {title: 'Weblio'}); 

            } else {
                console.log("here 1a");
                (new Error('Incorrect POST'));
                return res.render('editUserProfileError', {title: 'Weblio'}); 
            }
        });

};
```

Jade file:

```
extends layout
block content   
    div.centerContent

        form.validateForm(method="POST", action="/editUserProfile")
                legend Edit Profile
                input(type="text", name="firstName", maxlength="20", placeholder=ufirstName, value=ufirstName)
                br
                input(type="text", name="lastName", maxlength="20", placeholder=ulastName, value=ulastName)
                br
                input(type="email", name="email", maxlength="20", placeholder=uemail, value=uemail)
                br
                input(type="number", name="phone", maxlength="20", placeholder=uphone, value=uphone)
                br
                input(type="date", name="birthday", placeholder=ubirthday, value=ubirthday)
                br
                input.btn.btn-primary(type="submit", name="Update", value="Save")
                a(href="/userProfile")
                    button.btn(type="button") Cancel
```

This is my app.js file: I have a bunch of other things in there but the Register part is getting POST-ed so I don't think the app.js has any problems.

```
  app.get('/editUserProfile', user.editUserProfile);
  app.post('/editUserProfile', user.editUserProfilePost);
```

Updated:

```
exports.editUserProfilePost = function(req, res, err) {


            User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.signedCookies.userid,{
            firstName: req.body.firstName,
            lastName: req.body.lastName,
            email: req.body.email,
            phone: req.body.phone,
            birthday: new Date(req.body.birthday) 
        }, function(err) {
            if(!err) {
            console.log("post2");
            res.render('userProfile', {title: 'Weblio'}); 

        } else {
            console.log("post3");
            (new Error('Incorrect POST'));
            return res.render('editUserProfileError', {title: 'Weblio'}); 
        }
        });

};
```

Comment: You *do* have an `app.post('/editUserProfile', ...)` route somewhere, right?

Comment: yes let me update the code.

Comment: The console-messages in `editUserProfilePost` don't show up either? The error messages suggests a 404 error, which is strange. You're not using any middleware that might cause that response?

Comment: I have no idea whats happening. I use exactly the same stack and I code in a similar way, everything looks right to me. The only thing I do different but I think that it has nothing to do with your problem: instead of `exports.editUserProfilePost` I would use `module.exports.editUserProfilePost`! Can you try it?

Comment: Yeah, it does not change anything. I am not using any middleware, the only thing I can think of is that is there something I am not doing right in the mongoose schema? I am assuming the save inserts/updates the user so it should be the same, or am I suppose to add something in mongoose saying to updates a user's info?

Comment: I changed my mind and I think it might have somthing to do with your problem. Can you, at your `app.js` add this line: `console.log(user.editUserProfilePost);`- lets see if you are getting  `undefined` or `function`

Comment: So I suggest you to comment out everything withing `editUserProfilePost` and add the line `res.send(200)` - than post to this route and let me know if you get the response or you still get the same error.

Comment: @Lion789 when you want to update a record, you should retrieve it from the database, change it, and save it (or use [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate)/[`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate)), not create a new `User` instance. But still, if that were the problem it should have still shown your console.log's.

Comment: i got a function @Renato Gama

Comment: OK I do not know what happened but now it does POST but it keeps taking me to the error page (here3, here1a) show, even if the info is correct, let me try to do the find and update

Comment: @Lion789 also try console.logging the `err`, might give you a clue ;-)

Comment: Ok I added something on the bottom of my code, does that look right, I think I am writing something wrong

Comment: @Lion789 you need to pass it the user id as first argument, followed by the object with the updates, followed by a callback function (like with `save()`) ([something like this](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/4f9141ef2a07f859df94))

Comment: Sorry can you provide an example? I assumed that findByIdAndUpdate saves it as well?

Comment: @Lion789 yes, `findByIdAndUpdate` saves automatically. See my previous comment for a link to an example.

Comment: Ok that works I through the if statement i had inside that function, but I seem to have a problem with the error page loading if the form does not validate correctly? It seems like the error page does not get hit at all. I added it up top, only post2 gets hit.

Comment: @Lion789 the `if` only checks if the Mongoose operation caused an error; apparently, it doesn't.