# Node JS - Cannot POST if it isn't '/'?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, post, get

I have no idea what is wrong here as I have followed questions like [Node JS cannot post error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633049/node-js-cannot-post-error) and am trying to achieve a pretty simple task - just console.log what a form POSTS.

My problem is (Im using express) if I my form's action is anything other than '/' I get the error: `Cannot POST /search`

My form:

```
<form id="demo-2" method = "POST" action="/">
    <input type="search" name = "search" placeholder="Search">
                        </form>
```

. My index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var pg = require('pg');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/'));

// views is directory for all template files
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

//app.use(express.bodyParser());


//DIFFERENT APPS - tells them what to do

app.post('/', function(request, response) {
    //var username = req.body;

    console.log("posted something");
    response.end("something");
});

app.post('/search', function(request, response) {
    //var username = req.body;

    console.log("posted something");
    response.end("something2");
});

app.get('/search', function(request, response) {
     response.send("skylarr");

});

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
     //response.send("skylarr");
  response.render('pages/index');
```

I put both POST and GET funcs for both but I don't understand why the /search POST doesn't work when the /search GET does.

Comment: It should work, based on what you've shown. What is the full search URL?

Comment: localhost:5000/search

Comment: And is the search form html served from the `app.get('/'` endpoint?

Comment: same thing. local/search

Comment: What happens when the form action is omitted? You get the same *Cannot POST /search* error?